# IIS 6 force IIS to display hostname instead of ip address for dotnetnuke

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, iis-6, dotnetnuke

hope someone can provide me some insight on this iss problem!

Th situation is this, i understand that upgrading to IIS7 is absolutely necessary for security but will do so in the future but now, i'm using IIS6 and would like to force IIS6 to display qualified hostname of the IP address.

So far my other websites had gone through and been changed to display the qualified hostname but my dotnetnuke server (version 4.08.04), i am unable to locate the file(dnn or iis6) to change this.

I've used this procedure below for changing

IIS < 7
Force IIS to Display Hostname

It is possible to force IIS to display the hostname of the server instead of the IP address via the following:

```
Open a command window
Select "Start"
Select "Run"
Type in "cmd" and press enter or select the "OK" button
Browse to the "C:\inetpub\adminscripts" directory (or wherever this directory is located on your server)
Run the following commands:
adsutil set w3svc/UseHostName True
net stop iisadmin /y
net start w3svc
The IIS web service will now return the qualified hostname instead of the IP address.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a setting in DNN using the Ifinity Friendly URL provider http://www.ifinity.com.au/Products/Friendly_Url_Provider_For_DNN

Because you are on such an old version of DNN thought you might have to go back to a fairly old version of that provider to make it work. DNN 4.8.4 has quite a few security bugs, so upgrading to a later version of DNN (even on IIS 6) would be ideal.

I believe you could upgrade to DNN 6.2.8 (or whatever the last 6.* release was) without having to upgrade IIS, though you would need .NET 4.0 for any version of DNN after 5.1